# Gwibber doesn't work

Tags: gwibber

I have linked two accounts to it: twitter that seems to work because it is authorised and facebook that doesn't work at all, it is impossible to authorise :\ how to fix it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That looks very much like a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwibber/+bug/1058672).

In [Post #77](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gwibber/+bug/1058672/comments/77) they mention a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your social network is signed-in before using qwibber sometimes works when you get answers like this Facebook Error app not set up. Developers of this app have not set up this app properly for facebook log in. Had screenshot but, not sure how to attach it.